# How do I get access to object being described?

Tags: rspec

If I have an example such as the following:

```
describe "A flux capacitor" do
  it "should flux a lot" do
  # how can I access the string object "A flux capacitor" in here???
  ...
  end
end
```

How can I access the described string object "A flux capacitor"?
I've tried a few permutations of 'described_type' and 'described_class'
Such as:

```
self.described_type.to_s
```

But these always return nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
-Bill

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best way, but you can try:

`example_group_hierarchy.last.description`

which should return the descriptions of the "parent" example groups, concatenated as a string. The current example's description is just `description`.

If you want to get an array of descriptions:

`example_group_hierarchy.last.nested_descriptions`

I just found this by playing around in the console, so use at your own risk.